# D3.js - Date ticks don't align with data path - offset to the right

Tags: d3.js

As seen here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k7KE6/2/) the date ticks at the bottom do not align with the data path. Thursday 02 does not start at point zero. It is slightly shifted to the right.

I've tried many things and I can't figure it out. This only happens with the bottom axis and not with the data.

How can I make the dates start at the left corner? Thanks.

```
I'm not adding any code due to the extend of it. Please check link.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is because of time zone issues. All the dates will be offset by whatever your timezone offset to UTC is. To avoid this, don't rely on `new Date()` to create `Date` objects from your strings, but parse them explicitly. D3 provides a function to do this:

```
var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
```

Then you can parse like this:

```
parse(d.date);
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k7KE6/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Your lines match up to 05:00 every day.  So I just made the [isotime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) 05:00.  Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EV4LP/).

```
{"id":190688,"energy":"19518","date":"2013-11-07T05:00:00Z"}
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EV4LP/1/) is a little bit more elegant without editing the data.